# PHP can connect database but can't query any sql

Tags: php, mysql

I've installed php (5.4.16), php-mysql, php-fpm, nginx, MariaDB on CentOS 7. Now I can connect database with following code. But it can't execute any sql. I've checked the /etc/php.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php.d/mysql.ini and /etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini , and all of extensions have been enabled.

```
<?php
///print_r(phpinfo());exit;
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'XXXX;
    $dbname = 'XXXX';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
    if ($conn) {
        echo "Connection Successfully\n";
    } else {
        echo "Connection failed\n";
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `user` LIMIT 0, 10';

    try{

        if(mysql_query($sql,$conn)){
            echo "execute successfully";
        }else{
            echo "execute failed";
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }

?>
```

PHP info:

```
PHP Warning:  phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /var/www/lcpd/info.php on line 1
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.4.16

System => Linux host-10-6-101-2 3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 23 22:06:11 UTC 2015 x86_64
Build Date => Jun 23 2015 21:17:19
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/json.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php.d/zip.ini

PHP API => 20100412
PHP Extension => 20100525
Zend Extension => 220100525
Zend Extension Build => API220100525,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20100525,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => disabled
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => disabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

bz2

BZip2 Support => Enabled
Stream Wrapper support => compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support => bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version => 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010

calendar

Calendar support => enabled

Core

PHP Version => 5.4.16

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
always_populate_raw_post_data => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
asp_tags => Off => Off
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => no value => no value
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => Off => Off
display_startup_errors => Off => Off
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
exit_on_timeout => Off => Off
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php/modules => /usr/lib64/php/modules
file_uploads => On => On
highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php => .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.add_x_header => On => On
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 128M => 128M
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 8M => 8M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 16K => 16K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => GP => GP
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
serialize_precision => 17 => 17
short_open_tag => Off => Off
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sql.safe_mode => Off => Off
track_errors => Off => Off
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
upload_tmp_dir => no value => no value
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value

ctype

ctype functions => enabled

curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.29.0
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => Yes
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
Largefile => Yes
NTLM => Yes
SPNEGO => No
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
krb4 => No
libz => Yes
CharConv => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
SSL Version => NSS/3.15.4
ZLib Version => 1.2.7
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.4.3

date

date/time support => enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => UTC

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.timezone => no value => no value

ereg

Regex Library => Bundled library enabled

exif

EXIF Support => enabled
EXIF Version => 1.4 $Id$
Supported EXIF Version => 0220
Supported filetypes => JPEG,TIFF

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel => UCS-2LE => UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola => UCS-2BE => UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis => no value => no value
exif.encode_unicode => ISO-8859-15 => ISO-8859-15

fileinfo

fileinfo support => enabled
version => 1.0.5

filter

Input Validation and Filtering => enabled
Revision => $Id: 2aa8dd57d9c0c655cd45e6e5872bb95fa5ad76cf $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
filter.default => unsafe_raw => unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags => no value => no value

ftp

FTP support => enabled

gettext

GetText Support => enabled

gmp

gmp support => enabled
GMP version => 6.0.0

hash

hash support => enabled
Hashing Engines => md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost adler32 crc32 crc32b fnv132 fnv164 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5

iconv

iconv support => enabled
iconv implementation => glibc
iconv library version => 2.17

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
iconv.input_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding => ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-1

json

json support => enabled
json version => 1.2.1

libxml

libXML support => active
libXML Compiled Version => 2.9.1
libXML Loaded Version => 20901
libXML streams => enabled

mhash

MHASH support => Enabled
MHASH API Version => Emulated Support

mysql

MySQL Support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Client API version => 5.5.41-MariaDB
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE => external
MYSQL_SOCKET => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE => -I/usr/include/mysql
MYSQL_LIBS => -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysql.allow_persistent => On => On
mysql.connect_timeout => 60 => 60
mysql.default_host => no value => no value
mysql.default_password => no value => no value
mysql.default_port => no value => no value
mysql.default_socket => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.default_user => no value => no value
mysql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode => Off => Off

mysqli

MysqlI Support => enabled
Client API library version => 5.5.41-MariaDB
Active Persistent Links => 0
Inactive Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Client API header version => 5.5.41-MariaDB
MYSQLI_SOCKET => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
mysqli.default_socket => no value => no value
mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off

openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

pcntl

pcntl support => enabled

pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 8.32 2012-11-30

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => 5.5.41-MariaDB

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

pdo_sqlite

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
SQLite Library => 3.7.17

Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled
Phar EXT version => 2.0.1
Phar API version => 1.1.1
SVN revision => $Id: c5042cc34acebcc0926625b57dff03deebbe6472 $
Phar-based phar archives => enabled
Tar-based phar archives => enabled
ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
gzip compression => enabled
bzip2 compression => enabled
Native OpenSSL support => enabled


Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
phar.cache_list => no value => no value
phar.readonly => On => On
phar.require_hash => On => On

readline

Readline Support => enabled
Readline library => EditLine wrapper

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
cli.pager => no value => no value
cli.prompt => \b \>  => \b \>

Reflection

Reflection => enabled
Version => $Id: 6c4d8062369898a397e4b128348042f5c01b4427 $

session

Session Support => enabled
Registered save handlers => files user
Registered serializer handlers => php php_binary

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => Off => Off
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_secure => Off => Off
session.entropy_file => /dev/urandom => /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length => 32 => 32
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 1 => 1
session.hash_bits_per_character => 5 => 5
session.hash_function => 0 => 0
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => no value => no value
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => On => On
session.use_only_cookies => On => On
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0

shmop

shmop support => enabled

SimpleXML

Simplexml support => enabled
Revision => $Id: 692516840b2d7d6e7aedb0bedded1f53b764a99f $
Schema support => enabled

sockets

Sockets Support => enabled

SPL

SPL support => enabled
Interfaces => Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

sqlite3

SQLite3 support => enabled
SQLite3 module version => 0.7
SQLite Library => 3.7.17

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value

standard

Dynamic Library Support => enabled
Path to sendmail => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
assert.active => 1 => 1
assert.bail => 0 => 0
assert.callback => no value => no value
assert.quiet_eval => 0 => 0
assert.warning => 1 => 1
auto_detect_line_endings => 0 => 0
default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60
from => no value => no value
url_rewriter.tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent => no value => no value

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support => enabled

xml

XML Support => active
XML Namespace Support => active
libxml2 Version => 2.9.1

zip

Zip => enabled
Extension Version => $Id: 0c033d4e4613d577409950ed7bf8da4b68286d15 $
Zip version => 1.11.0
Compiled against libzip version => 0.10.1

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.7
Linked Version => 1.2.7

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

Additional Modules

Module Name

Environment

Variable => Value
XDG_SESSION_ID => 21
HOSTNAME => host-10-6-101-2
SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED =>
TERM => xterm-256color
SHELL => /bin/bash
HISTSIZE => 1000
SSH_CLIENT => 180.175.175.173 2401 22
SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE =>
SSH_TTY => /dev/pts/0
USER => root
LS_COLORS => rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:
MAIL => /var/spool/mail/root
PATH => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
PWD => /var/www/lcpd
LANG => en_US.UTF-8
SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED =>
HISTCONTROL => ignoredups
SHLVL => 1
HOME => /root
LOGNAME => root
SSH_CONNECTION => 180.175.175.173 2401 10.6.101.2 22
LC_CTYPE => UTF-8
LESSOPEN => ||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR => /run/user/0
_ => /usr/bin/php
OLDPWD => /var/www

PHP Variables

Variable => Value
_SERVER["XDG_SESSION_ID"] => 21
_SERVER["HOSTNAME"] => host-10-6-101-2
_SERVER["SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED"] =>
_SERVER["TERM"] => xterm-256color
_SERVER["SHELL"] => /bin/bash
_SERVER["HISTSIZE"] => 1000
_SERVER["SSH_CLIENT"] => 180.175.175.173 2401 22
_SERVER["SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE"] =>
_SERVER["SSH_TTY"] => /dev/pts/0
_SERVER["USER"] => root
_SERVER["LS_COLORS"] => rs=0:di=38;5;27:ln=38;5;51:mh=44;38;5;15:pi=40;38;5;11:so=38;5;13:do=38;5;5:bd=48;5;232;38;5;11:cd=48;5;232;38;5;3:or=48;5;232;38;5;9:mi=05;48;5;232;38;5;15:su=48;5;196;38;5;15:sg=48;5;11;38;5;16:ca=48;5;196;38;5;226:tw=48;5;10;38;5;16:ow=48;5;10;38;5;21:st=48;5;21;38;5;15:ex=38;5;34:*.tar=38;5;9:*.tgz=38;5;9:*.arc=38;5;9:*.arj=38;5;9:*.taz=38;5;9:*.lha=38;5;9:*.lz4=38;5;9:*.lzh=38;5;9:*.lzma=38;5;9:*.tlz=38;5;9:*.txz=38;5;9:*.tzo=38;5;9:*.t7z=38;5;9:*.zip=38;5;9:*.z=38;5;9:*.Z=38;5;9:*.dz=38;5;9:*.gz=38;5;9:*.lrz=38;5;9:*.lz=38;5;9:*.lzo=38;5;9:*.xz=38;5;9:*.bz2=38;5;9:*.bz=38;5;9:*.tbz=38;5;9:*.tbz2=38;5;9:*.tz=38;5;9:*.deb=38;5;9:*.rpm=38;5;9:*.jar=38;5;9:*.war=38;5;9:*.ear=38;5;9:*.sar=38;5;9:*.rar=38;5;9:*.alz=38;5;9:*.ace=38;5;9:*.zoo=38;5;9:*.cpio=38;5;9:*.7z=38;5;9:*.rz=38;5;9:*.cab=38;5;9:*.jpg=38;5;13:*.jpeg=38;5;13:*.gif=38;5;13:*.bmp=38;5;13:*.pbm=38;5;13:*.pgm=38;5;13:*.ppm=38;5;13:*.tga=38;5;13:*.xbm=38;5;13:*.xpm=38;5;13:*.tif=38;5;13:*.tiff=38;5;13:*.png=38;5;13:*.svg=38;5;13:*.svgz=38;5;13:*.mng=38;5;13:*.pcx=38;5;13:*.mov=38;5;13:*.mpg=38;5;13:*.mpeg=38;5;13:*.m2v=38;5;13:*.mkv=38;5;13:*.webm=38;5;13:*.ogm=38;5;13:*.mp4=38;5;13:*.m4v=38;5;13:*.mp4v=38;5;13:*.vob=38;5;13:*.qt=38;5;13:*.nuv=38;5;13:*.wmv=38;5;13:*.asf=38;5;13:*.rm=38;5;13:*.rmvb=38;5;13:*.flc=38;5;13:*.avi=38;5;13:*.fli=38;5;13:*.flv=38;5;13:*.gl=38;5;13:*.dl=38;5;13:*.xcf=38;5;13:*.xwd=38;5;13:*.yuv=38;5;13:*.cgm=38;5;13:*.emf=38;5;13:*.axv=38;5;13:*.anx=38;5;13:*.ogv=38;5;13:*.ogx=38;5;13:*.aac=38;5;45:*.au=38;5;45:*.flac=38;5;45:*.mid=38;5;45:*.midi=38;5;45:*.mka=38;5;45:*.mp3=38;5;45:*.mpc=38;5;45:*.ogg=38;5;45:*.ra=38;5;45:*.wav=38;5;45:*.axa=38;5;45:*.oga=38;5;45:*.spx=38;5;45:*.xspf=38;5;45:
_SERVER["MAIL"] => /var/spool/mail/root
_SERVER["PATH"] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
_SERVER["PWD"] => /var/www/lcpd
_SERVER["LANG"] => en_US.UTF-8
_SERVER["SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED"] =>
_SERVER["HISTCONTROL"] => ignoredups
_SERVER["SHLVL"] => 1
_SERVER["HOME"] => /root
_SERVER["LOGNAME"] => root
_SERVER["SSH_CONNECTION"] => 180.175.175.173 2401 10.6.101.2 22
_SERVER["LC_CTYPE"] => UTF-8
_SERVER["LESSOPEN"] => ||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
_SERVER["XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"] => /run/user/0
_SERVER["_"] => /usr/bin/php
_SERVER["OLDPWD"] => /var/www
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] => info.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] => info.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] => info.php
_SERVER["PATH_TRANSLATED"] => info.php
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] =>
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"] => 1438831459.0191
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] => 1438831459
_SERVER["argv"] => Array
(
    [0] => info.php
)

_SERVER["argc"] => 1

PHP License
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the PHP License as published by the PHP Group
and included in the distribution in the file:  LICENSE

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any
questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.
```

BTW:I can get the result with mysql cli

Comment: Stop using MySQL, it is deprecated. Either use PDO or MySQLi. Is it showing any errors? Is error reporting enabled?

Comment: I agree. Use mysqli (i.e. mysqli_connect(...) and mysqli_query(); //order of the arguments/parameters varies from mysql_query();

Could you also let us know if you are getting an exception or simply "execute failed" message?

Comment: @AkshaySharma It just output 'Connection Successfully' and 'execute failed', no exception shown

Comment: Try this: Instead of using: echo "execute failed";
try using: echo "execute failed. ".mysql_error(); //this will tell you what's wrong. (Returns the last MySQL error occurred).

Comment: let me guess, no user table in db

Comment: What do you get when you run your program? Error message? Did the `execute failed` shows up?

Comment: @DrewPierce I can get db from mysql

Comment: @LoganWayne It just output 'Connection Successfully' and 'execute failed', no exception shown

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

  // error reporting initialized, for use in development/staging, not production

  // remember, this is a test. Do not use root otherwise
  $dbhost = "localhost";
  $dbuser = "root";
  $dbpass = "xxxx";
  $dbname = "xxxx";

  // note to self: we will be using mysqli_* functions

  // from OP's phpinfo:
  // MysqlI Support => enabled
  // Client API library version => 5.5.41-MariaDB

  $conn=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connect Failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
  }

  // Perform a query, check for error
  $query="SELECT * FROM `user` LIMIT 0, 10";
  if (!mysqli_query($conn,$query)) {
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
  }
  echo "Successfully made it here !";

?>
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.